# Direct proof problem

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

Prove: If $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $7n-3$ is odd, then $n$ is even.

If I assume that $n$ is odd, I can get the required contradiction, but I want to use a direct proof. Is there anyway to do this?

Comment: $7n-3=2k+1\implies 7n=2k+4=2(k+2)\implies 2\,|\,7n\implies 2\,|\,n$.

Comment: You don't get a proof by contradiction. You get a proof by contrapositive. That's a lot more direct.

Comment: $7n -3 \equiv n+1 \equiv 1 \mod 2 \Rightarrow n \equiv 0 \mod 2$

Answer (score 6):

If $7n-3$ is odd, then $7n$ is even, thus $n$ is even. Simple as that.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $7n-3$ is odd. Then $7n-3 =2k+1$ where $k \in \mathbb{Z}$. Subtracting $6n-3$ from both sides of the equation yields:

$n=2k+1-6n+3 = 2(k-3n+2) = 2m$, where $m =k-3n+2 \in \mathbb{Z}$. Thus, $n$ is even.